# How to get html after content changed

Tags: c#, dom, webforms

On my code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
     myDiv.innerHtml = "<span>potato</span>"
}
```

I place some html in myDiv. This is the html:

```
<div id="myDiv" runat="server"></div>
<form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <button runat="server" onserverclick="Save_OnClick">Confirm changes</button>
</form>
```

After the page completly loads I see `<span>potato</span>` inside my div.

However, if I have javascript events that change `myDiv` content to something like `<span>fish</span>` and I want to retrieve the html content of `myDiv` inside c# `save_onclick` event I receive `<span>potato</span>` **when i was expecting** `<span>fish</span>`.

```
protected void Save_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myDivHtml = myDiv.InnerHtml;
    }
```

Its like if the DOM didnt refresh for the server side.

How can i solve this? I mean get the html AFTER javascript interaction, or **is there another way of doing this?**

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a timer that checks the last write time of your html file against a static DateTime object.
2. When the last write time of the html file's last write time does not equal the static DateTime, call a method with a StreamReader.

**Example Code**

```
class MyClass
{
    static string divContent;
    static DateTime compareTime;

    private void timerGrip_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists("yourFile.htm"))
        {
            DateTime tempDateTime = File.GetLastWriteTime("yourFile.htm");

            if (tempDateTime != compareTime)
            {
                compareTime = tempDateTime;
                GetDivContent();
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetDivContent()
    {
        string tempString = string.Empty;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("yourFile.htm");

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            tempString = reader.ReadLine();
            if (tempString.Contains("<div id=\"myDiv\""))
                break;
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempString))
            divContent = tempString.Substring(31, tempString.Length - 37);

        reader.Close();
    }
}
```